# Do I need to understand how Haskell represents data to be able to write good Haskell programs?

Tags: java, data-structures, compiler-construction, haskell, heap-memory

I'm learning Haskell from a Java background.  When I program Java, I feel like I have a strong understanding of how objects are laid out in memory and the consequences of this.  For example I know exactly how `java.lang.String` and `java.util.LinkedList` work and therefore I know how I should use them.  With Haskell I'm a bit lost.  For example, how does `(:)` work?  Should I care?  Is it specified somewhere?

Comment: It is a good question because I have seen people prefixing values with a ! for this very reason.

Comment: In general you shouldn't need to know the internals of Java classes either (decoupling, information hiding, encapsulation...).

Comment: @musiKk I agree you shouldn't need to read the source code but I do think it helps to know, broadly, how something is implemented.  For example the difference between LinkedList and ArrayList is easy to understand because the names strongly hint at the implementation and I don't have to consult the documentation to discover if a method is O(1) or O(n) or whatever.  If you just give me a List, I don't know how the operations will perform without reading the documentation.

Comment: all data in Haskell are defined as trees which unfold outwards... so there's really one obvious choice for how to implement a simple list: a singly-linked list. You can do things with mutable arrays if you're working inside monads of various ilk, but that's a fairly advanced topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is no. When programming in Haskell you should think of your data structures as pure mathematical objects and not worry about how they're represented in memory. The reason for this is that, in the absence of side-effects, there's really nothing *to* data except the functions that create it and the functions you can use to extract the simpler parts out of which it was constructed.

To see information about data constructors like `(:)`, or any other terms, use the `:type` (or just `:t` for short) command inside GHCi:

```
:Prelude> :type (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

That tells you that the `(:)` constructor (pronounced "cons"), takes a value of any type, and a list of the same type, and returns a list of the same type. You can also get a bit more info by using the `:info` command. This will show you what the data definition looks like:

```
Prelude> :info (:)
data [] a = ... | a : [a]   -- Defined in GHC.Types
infixr 5 :
```

This tells you that `(:)` is the constructor which prepends an element to an existing list.

I also highly recommend [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) not only for looking up things by name but for doing the reverse kind of search; where you know the signature of the function you're looking for and want to find if someone's already written it for you. Hoogle is nice because it gives descriptions and example usages.

#### Shapes of Inductive Data

I said above that it's not important to know the representation of your data in memory... you should, however, understand the *shape* of the data you're dealing with, to avoid poor performance decisions. All data in Haskell is inductively defined, meaning it has a tree-like shape which unfolds ever outwards recursively. You can tell the shape of data by looking at its definition; there's really nothing hidden about its performance characteristics once you know how to read this:

```
data MyList a = Nil | Cons a (MyList a)
```

As you can see from the definition, the only way you can get a new `MyList` is by the `Cons` constructor. If you use this constructor multiple times, you'll end up with something roughly of this shape:

```
(Cons a5 (Cons a4 (Cons a3 (Cons a2 (Cons a1 Nil)))))
```

It's just a tree with no branches, that's the definition of a list! And the only way to get at `a1` is by popping off each of the `Cons`s in turn; hence access to the last element is **O(n)**, whereas access to the head is constant time. Once you can do this kind of reasoning about data structures based on their definitions, you're all set.

Comment: +1 for Hoogle alone. Every Haskell programmer should know and use it. It's a great tool.

Comment: It's probably also worth pointing out that a value (such as a list) that's only used in one place often (? always?) won't actually exist --- the producing and consuming functions get fused together and the list representation is skipped.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic description.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is "no", you don't need to know about data layouts -- a knowledge of complexity will be useful though.

To write highly optimized Haskell programs, a good working knowledge of the shape of data structures in the heap is essential, however. A tool to help this is ["vacuum"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vacuum-cairo), which can render diagrams of Haskell data structures as they are laid out.

Some examples:

```
$ view "hello"
```

[image: linked lists]

```
$ view (IntMap.fromList $ zip [1..10] [1..])
```

[image: Data.IntMap]

Here's a short video of how to use the tool: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4-212uMgy8